# ASP.NET Core 3.1 service.AddControllerWithViews not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a controller and my `startup.cs` is defined like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigurationServices(IServiceCollection service)
        {
            service.AddControllersWithViews();
            // service.AddControllers(); tried adding this line did not work
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However on running the application, I am getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'

Please help.

`HomeController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string Index() // called action methods
        {
            return "Some string";
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any additional details are required

Comment: I am sorry but what is the problem?  What do you want service.AddControllersWithViews(); or  service.AddControllers(); ? Or maybe AddMvc  and why?

Comment: I want to addControllerWithViews because I want to create controllers aswell as views.. I have already created a test controller and i expect it to work when i do endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); however I am getting this error

Comment: You error message shows that you are  using AddControllers only. Can you show your test controller that is not working pls?

Comment: Hi @Phil, I try your `Startup` and `HomeController` in my project, It all works fine, Have you made any other changes to your project?

Answer (score 1):

since you are need controller with views, not api one, try this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.. I've added my controller can you pls check ?